# Installation of GNU Octave on Ubuntu platform

Tags: ubuntu, octave

I have installed octave-3.6.3 on ubuntu platform using the link https://askubuntu.com/questions/194151/how-do-you-install-the-latest-version-of-gnu-octave

On sudo make install, I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/texi2dvi: pdfetex exited with bad status, quitting.
make[3]: *** [octave.pdf] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/octave-3.6.3/doc/interpreter'
make[2]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/octave-3.6.3/doc'
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/octave-3.6.3'
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

Please help.

Comment: The link is very old, what Ubuntu are you using? Try installing from the software center. GNU Octave 3.8 has been released December 31, 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you looking for instructions in Stack Overflow instead of straight from the Octave website? They even have a wiki page targeted at [Debian based distributions](http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Debian_systems) (such as Ubuntu). At the bottom of the page, it has a table of all required dependencies. What more could you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Octave cloud instead of installing, it might work better for you. You can try it here - https://octave.im/